# How to cancel replica request through softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have setup of replication, where i have source volume at one site & replica at another site. Now i want to cancel the replica request through Softlayer python API.(not through portal)
I have checked there are 2 services related to billing;

```
SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem
SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request::createObject
```

Which service i should use & how?
Can someone please help me to get that API.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method:

- [SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject)

Follow these steps for that:

### 1. Retrieve accountId and replica's billing item

First, its necessary to retrieve billingItem from replica, Make the following request for it. (This request will return **accountId** and **billingItemId** from replica)

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$storageId/getReplicationPartners?objectMask=accountId;billingItem.id

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$storageId** with your own information

---

### 2. Cancel the replica

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "accountId": $accountId,
         "items":[  
            {  
               "billingItemId": $billingItemId,
               "immediateCancellationFlag": true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey**, **$accountId** and **$billingItemId** with your own information.